# Install SQL Server 2017 over 2016 Local DB and 2012 native client

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, sql-server-localdb, native-client

I have downloaded Microsoft SQL Sever 2017 and would like to install it. But just to be sure I checked installed applications and I found that there is:

- Microsoft SQL Server 2012 native client
- Microsoft SQL Server 2016 LocalDB

installed already. ( I noticed that because there was a Microsoft SQL Server folder in Program Files)

Can I just proceed with the installation? 
I don't recall having installed SQL server previously so I am not sure why those two are installed in the first place

Also, I would like to have SQL Server management studio installed. Is this a separated install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL Server 2012 Native Client is a client library for connecting to SQL Server, and SQL Server 2012 is the latest version. Installing SQL Server 2017 will not impact this, and vice-versa. More [details here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/sql-server-native-client?view=sql-server-2017).

LocalDB is a feature of the Express Edition of SQL Server used by developers for testing against SQL Server with minimal configuration and overhead. You can install SQL Server 2017 side-by-side with a LocalDB instance without any issues. More [details here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-2017).

SQL Server Management Studio has been separated from the SQL Server installation media since SQL Server 2016. You need to download and install SSMS separately from SQL Server. Download [link here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017).